# Opera Mini vs Opera Mobile

Tags: browser, opera

Not surprisingly I'm having some troubles with Internet Explorer on my new smartphone that runs Windows Mobile 6.5 and I was looking into installing the new beta version of Opera Mini, but I also saw Opera Mobile and now I'm really confused.

What are the key differences between the two? Which one would be more appropriate to install?

Comment: I found [the difference](http://www.opera.com/products/choose/). Seems like Opera Mini can't process Javascript very well.

Comment: Can't see anything relevant to Javascript processing there. Are you sure you pasted the correct link?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps I'm out of date, but I recall that all of Opera Mini traffic passes through the Opera servers to be compresses and transmogrified for the small screen. Opera Mobile, on the other hand is truly a stand alone browser (which is why it is "heavier").

Privacy wonks seem to get twitchy about Mini (traffic through other servers, password security, etc.).

If Mini interests you, you may also want to give Skyfire a look.

Comment: compression is optional with Mobile (aka Turbo mode)

Comment: Good point Molly. I forgot that was in the newest version. Thanks Alix :-)